# How to make the CNN prediction function output as binary number(0 or 1)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, prediction, image-classification

I used the CNN model with Keras to make an image binary classification, during the final prediction part, I defined such function below to output the prediction result:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = ((256,256,3))))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 512, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                      loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=valid_ds,
    epochs=10)

def testing_image(image_directory):
    test_image = image.load_img(image_directory, target_size = (256, 256))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    result = model.predict(test_image)
    print(result)

testing_image('/content/drive/MyDrive/testing/01.jpg')
```

The output is:

```
[[0.4733843]]
```

The output is always a decimal number, but I want the output the result as only
`0`or `1` and without the array representation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Something along the lines of `result >= 0.5` should give you predictions of 0 or 1. This is also how you'd calculate your class prediction in the binary case.

Comment: @Tinu I tried `return (result >= 0.5).astype('int32')`, it returned `array([[1]], dtype=int32)`, the result is nice but what if I only want the result as `1` without any other characters?

Comment: instead of `print(result)` write this line : `return (result[0][0] >= 0.5).astype(np.int16)`

Answer (score 1):

[Sigmoid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/sigmoid) activation function returns the values between 0 to 1 where the values <0.5 implies to category zero(0) and >0.5 implies to category one(1) in binary classification.

To get these binary numbers, you need to add one more line of code in `testing_image()` as below:

**Fixed code:**

```
def testing_image(image_directory):
    test_image = image.load_img(image_directory, target_size = (256, 256))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
#Changes in code
    pred = model.predict(test_image)
    result = np.where(pred > 0.5, 1, 0) #<--to get the binary category
    print(result)
testing_image('/content/drive/MyDrive/testing/01.jpg')
```